# How can I know how long each of the other devices has been connected to the router from the Bash?

Tags: bash, router, debian

I have a router (tp-link TD-W8961N). Several devices are connected wirelessly to this router. I have a PC with Linux Debian 10. Using my PC (Debian 10), how can I know how long each of the other devices has been connected to the router from the Bash? Although from the router administrator page I can know the devices that are connected, how can I know the devices connected to this router from the Bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router's [manual](https://static.tp-link.com/2020/202007/20200708/1910012832_TD-W8961N(EU).pdf) shows that you can view the device log by going to the Status / System Log -tab. The manual doesn't actually show whether client association / disassociation events are logged in the first place, but if they are, that's where you'll find them.

The Save button allows you to save the log to your own system. It should be saved as some sort of text file which you can then analyze using standard tools like `cat`, `less`, `grep` etc. The clients can be identified by the MAC addresses associated with the events.

Unfortunately this router's specs are too low to support WRT-based firmwares that would provide more advanced capabilities.